# How to install LuaJIT on FreeBSD without using Gmake?

Tags: freebsd, compiling, make

Has anyone been able to install LuaJIT v2 on FreeBSD AMD64(x64) without using Gmake (just freebsd-make)?

If so how?

When I attempt to use freebsd-make, LuaJIT doesn't build.

Comment: Why do you constraint yourself to not using gmake?  I understand the developers who want more portability than just to gmake, but not a user who don't accept to use prerequisites of the developers.  Would you ask the same question for ant or bjam or a 3rd party library?

Comment: @AProgrammer, because I don't want any GNU/GPL software on my server (which is the philosophy of FreeBSD). LuaJIT is under the MIT license, but by default - it used Gmake to build the software. Gmake is obviously GPL'ed.

Comment: If you want a OS without GPL software, don't use FreeBSD. They ship the OS with GCC and binutils. I don't understand the problem if you have now others very big GPL project installed. Anyway, the best option for your problem in my opinion is rewrite the makefile gmake->fbsd-make. It's not difficult.

Answer (score 4):

You can deinstall gmake again after building luajit.

Another option would be to use luajit 1.x which builds with bsd make.

The Makefile is a GNU Makefile, you would have to rewrite the Makefile.

Comment: Agreed.  JasonH, while I respect your desire to minimize GPL, it's the LuaJIT project itself that is still GPL-ish (by using gmake).  Unless you contribute a BSD-make-compatible makefile back to the project, you've already signed up for a hybrid license, so your philosophical stand is moot for this particular port.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use portmaster, there is an option to automatically install build dependancies from packages (ie. gmake) and than deinstall them right after installation finishes.